# Using varchar(14) as datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, lamp

I'm working with a database that's using `varchar(14)` as a datetime datatype and in older tables, it's working smoothly as a datetime type with functions like `DATEDIFF()`.

I tried to use this format to create a new table and remain consistent in this project and it's not working with datetime functions. Is there any convert macros, custom data types, or global functions that may be referencing these older columns that I need to update for my new table? Where would I look for these?

Given these two tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE `working` (
  `id` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timecomplete` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`count`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `notWorking` (
  `count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `delDate` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`count`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

With the first i can query `SELECT id FROM working WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), timecomplete) >1;` and all is well.

On the second, `SELECT id FROM notWorking WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), delDate) >1;` returns the warning: `Incorrect datetime value: '2018040305000'` which while correct doesn't help me much.

Comment: You need to parse that string to date, mysql has "STR_TO_DATE" function,

Comment: How can you fit "datetime" in 14 chars? Is it `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`?

Comment: The format is `YYYYMMDDHHmmss` like you said, @PaulSpiegel. I'm content with parsing it but it seems to happen automatically on older tables. Is there a global setting to convert all Varchar(14) to Datetime? I appreciate you both not just suggesting to use Datetime instead btw.

Comment: Please give examples of data that “works” and data that “doesn’t work” with details of exactly *how* it doesn’t work. And provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just wanted to write "use DATETIME" :-)

Comment: The docs say it should work. "MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats: ... As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' or 'YYMMDDHHMMSS'" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html - And it works for me.

Comment: Updated with a MVCE. The problem was the date I was saving was missing the last digit.

Comment: Thanks you both @Bohemian & Paul, this solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue where a varchar(14) wasn't working as a DateTime type in MySQL. It turns out I was missing a single digit. Documentation on this can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Specifically, this line answered a lot of my questions in terms of this being supported by MySQL.

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>
> As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' or
>   'YYMMDDHHMMSS' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>   For example, '20070523091528' and '070523091528' are interpreted as
>   '2007-05-23 09:15:28', but '071122129015' is illegal (it has a
>   nonsensical minute part) and becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.